# Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, error

Client is trying to setup promotions via the admin but when saving and applying the promotion the server logs the following error (admin return blank screen):

> PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a
>   non-object in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php
>   on line 855

Unable to find any info regarding this type of error, what may be causing it, or how to correct it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This error is being thrown because an attempt to load an attribute instance is failing when `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::getAllAttributeValues` is called. Can you provide a backtrace for this error? Fatal errors should record a complete backtrace in the PHP error log along with the error message.

Answer (score 8):

Use the following script to list product attributes with non-existant backend models:

```
umask(0);
require 'app/Mage.php';    
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
Mage::app('admin');

$entityType = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getEntityType('catalog_product');
foreach ($entityType->getAttributeCollection() as $attribute) {
    if ($backendClass = $attribute->getBackendModel()) {
        try {
            class_exists(Mage::getConfig()->getModelClassName($backendClass), true);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Not found the backend model {$backendClass} for product attribute {$attribute->getAttributeCode()}\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this code really helped me in finding the error

Comment: Note that you can do the same for 'catalog_category', 'customer' and 'customer_address' to find all possible sources of 'Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object", not only in Product/Collection.php