# error to add custom attributes

Tags: attributes, customer

I am on a site magento 1.7.0.2

I created a module to add an attribute in the customer account.
At first it worked, my field has been added and then I realized that I had made a spelling mistake.

so I deleted directly attribute from phpmyadmin.

And when I relaunched the website I get this error when I go to customer management:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object
```

I tried many things but I have found no solution.

Here are my files :

```
$installer = $this;


$installer->startSetup();

$this->addAttribute('customer', 'demande', array(
    'type' => 'int', // varchar, text, int, static, datetime
    'input' => 'boolean', // text, select, date
    'label' => 'Demande de compte professionnel',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => 1
));


/**
 * Si attribut de type select :
 * 'type' => 'select',
 * 'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_table',
 * 'option' => array('values' => array('Mon Option 1', 'Mon Option 2')),
 */

Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('customer', 'demande')
    ->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'checkout_register'))
    ->save();


$installer->endSetup();
```

my config.xml file :

> 

```
 <admin>
    <routers>
        <customfield>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Digitgold_Demande</module>
                <frontName>customfield</frontName>
            </args>
        </customfield>
    </routers>
</admin>

<global>
    <fieldsets>
        <customer_account>
             <demande><create>1</create><update>1</update><name>1</name></demande>
        </customer_account>
    </fieldsets>
</global>
<global>
    <resources>
        <customfield_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Digitgold_Customer</module>
                <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </customfield_setup>
        <customfield_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </customfield_write>
        <customfield_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </customfield_read>
    </resources>
</global>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your issue may have something to with used_in_forms keys didn't get deleted.

```
Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('customer', 'demande')
    ->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'checkout_register'))
    ->save();
```

Take a look at database table `customer_form_attribute` and compare it with a older backup

To remove attribute the correct way

```
/* @var $installer Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup */
$installer->startSetup();\
// Remove Product Attribute
$installer->removeAttribute('customer', 'product_attribute_code');
```

To fix your issue see [Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5745/call-to-a-member-function-getbackend-on-a-non-object)

Comment: I mistake again.

I tried the script also but it returns me a blank page.

I do not know what to do

Comment: do you have a backup db to recreate the row you manually deleted?

Comment: my backups are created night and I create and delete the attribute in the day

Comment: I would try to create a new attribute (exactly the same except for the attribute code on a dev box). Then use it as a sample to recreate the row you manually deleted. Then try to delete both programmatically

Comment: it's just when I want to recreate an attribute that I come across this error.when i desactivate the module, I no longer have this error

Comment: Can you add the attribute install script to your question above

Comment: ok no problem.I do this

Comment: this is done.the code is down

Comment: it's done i update the original question

Comment: i compared with the table customer_form_attribute and there is no difference