# magento vsprintf() [function.vsprintf]: Too few arguments translate.php

Tags: magento-1.8, error

I was getting a white screen on my store, so i was trying to debug the error and it was showing this error. Anyone knows how to fix it?

```
    Array
(
    [type] => 2
    [message] => vsprintf() [function.vsprintf]: Too few arguments
    [file] => /home/vhosts/MYSITE/subdomains/test/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php
    [line] => 416
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens if a translation requires variables (printf syntax, usually `%s` or `%d`) but they are not provided.

Trace the error and watch out for `__('something %s something')` - it should be `__('something %s something', 'something')`

Comment: There are no % in translate.php. Could u give us some advice?

Comment: Translate.php is not the **source** of the error. Don't you see a stack trace?

Comment: We where fixing a other error first. This one: Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/vhosts/MYSITE/httpdocs/includes/src/Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract.php on line 514 But someone said that was a module error so i needed to uninstall every costum module one by one., but we accidentally deleted Mage_core

Comment: That was bad advice. This error message is usually the **result** of an uninstalled module that is still referenced in a product attribute. But I don't see how this is related to the question?

Comment: Because when we deleted mage core. We got this error and a blank sceen on every page. And after we deleted all the products we still get the error with the abstract.

Comment: Ok, i fixed it myself i just enabled mage_core in the database. But now i still get the  Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/vhosts/mysite/subdomains/test/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php on line 514 error

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5745/call-to-a-member-function-getbackend-on-a-non-object

Comment: i used your script and it said this Mage registry key "original_include_path" already exists do you know how to fix this?